How to argue that Büchi arithmetic is more expressive than Presburger arithmetic
Büchi arithmetic is expressively equivalent to WS1S.
How can I show that WS1S is strictly more expressive than Presburger arithmetic?
Is there a simple argument for this?

The set $\{2^n \mid n \geqslant 0\}$ is definable in Büchi arithmetic, but not in Presburger arithmetic.
